# Column Mapping on Multi-columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Df1:

```
Country Sex Year Bin
NZ      M   2005  1
NZ      F   2005  1
NZ      M   2007  3
KR      F   2005  2
```

...
Df2:

```
Country Sex Year Rate
NZ      M   2005  0.5
NZ      M   2006  0.4
NZ      F   2005  0.6
NZ      F   2006  0.3
```

...
Desired Outcome:

```
Country Sex Year Bin Rate
NZ      M   2005  1   0.5
NZ      F   2005  1   0.6
NZ      M   2007  3   NaN
KR      F   2005  2   NaN
```

How do I join the dataframe of Df2 to achieve the desired outcome by matching the input on [Country, Sex and Year] of Df1. 
I've attempted merge/join but it seems to only recognize 1 column as the criteria for mapping and ended up joining all inputs together..

Comment: What do you get for `df1.merge(df2, how='left')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
result = pd.merge(DF1, DF2, how='left', on=['Country', 'Sex','Year'])
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of 'on', actually tried it but using double [[..]] for multiple columns.. which ended up in error. Thanks again!

Comment: @DevinLee:- welcome!!